# Prove a graph G is bipartite iff its cycle space has a basis s.t. each vector in the basis has an even number of non-zero entries?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, vector-spaces, bipartite-graphs

I know if G is bipartite, all cycles in the graph will have even length. Hence the characteristic vectors of all the cycles in G will all have an even number of non-zero entries, which means such a basis exists.
How do I prove the converse? 
Ie, 'if there is a basis of the cycle space of G such that each vector has an even number of non-zero entries, then G is bipartite'?

Answer (score 0):

We can proceed:

- Assume there is a basis of the cycle space of G such that each vector has an even number of non-zero entries.
- Assume G is not bipartite, and thus G has an odd cycle, with characteristic vector v and an odd number of non-zero entries.
- By definition of a basis, v is a linear combination of the basis vectors.
- Find a contradiction by counting non-zero entries mod 2 in this linear combination.